# How to change target to "Everyone" instead of using target "channels" in parse Push Notification

Tags: android, wordpress, push-notification, parse-platform, google-cloud-messaging

Hiii, I am using parse push for push Notification in android which is working fine when i tried it manually from parse.com ,but the problem comes out when i use WordPress for sending notifications from its posts automatically.because when WordPress sends post the device can't receive any notification and when i check my dashboard in parse.com the target i saw is channels.Now i want to know that how i change my target to "everyone" instead of "channels".

The code :

```
ParseAnalytics.trackAppOpened(getIntent());
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
if(!prefs.getBoolean("firstTime", false)) {
PushService.subscribe(getBaseContext(), "", Home.class);
showToast("You are subscribed for the push Notification You can unsubscribe it in Settings");
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
editor.putBoolean("firstTime", true);
editor.commit();
}

// inform the Parse Cloud that it is ready for notifications
PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(this, Home.class);


ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();
```

Comment: Which Parse SDK you are using to send messages ?

Comment: code would be useful, can you paste the portion of the code where you are pushing the notif ?

Comment: @Aadi yes of course ,let me add that in answer

Comment: Have you tried pushing from the web console ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have kept the prefrence option here so that it will get executed only once ,check the code and let me know ....

```
 ParseAnalytics.trackAppOpened(getIntent());
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    if(!prefs.getBoolean("firstTime", false)) {
    PushService.subscribe(getBaseContext(), "", Home.class);
    showToast("You are subscribed for the push Notification You can unsubscribe it in Settings");
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putBoolean("firstTime", true);
    editor.commit();
    }

    // inform the Parse Cloud that it is ready for notifications
    PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(this, Home.class);


    ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();
```